# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, None, 9000) but got array with shape (9000, 1, 4)

Tags: python, keras

I simply want to make my model work, but running it produces following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, None, 9000) but got array with shape (9000, 1, 4)
```

I've read every thread about problems with shape 3 times, but got no answer that would help me.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/TSt4M3T1) is my code.

What should I change to get proper shape? Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Please put your actual code in the question rather than using a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have given the input shape as (None,9000) in this line

```
model.add(Dense(units = 64, input_shape = (None, 9000)))
```

But your input data is of the shape (9000,1,4).Hence you should change the input shape as

```
model.add(Dense(units = 64, input_shape = (1, 4)))
```

The first dimension need not be specified in input_shape